# interacting with linux shell prompt in Java

Tags: java, linux

```
Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.setWorkingDirectory("/var/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/Telegram/tg")
CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -U root");
int exitvalue = exec.execute(cl);
```

How can I get output of this command:

```
exec.execute(cl);
```

and run other related commands on telegram-cli command prompt e.g. contact_list, msg contact "Hello world";

Comment: Which library are you using to do this?  It doesn't look like built in classes.

Comment: I am not using any library but this software is installed on our dedicated server. I am trying to use simple java techniques to run program and its relevant commands

Comment: You are using a library, which is an important realisation because once you know which library you are using, you can read it's documentation on how to use it.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Comment: The fact that you didn't install it yourself doesn't mean it's not a library...

Comment: Ok its library. What you please suggest regarding printing output in java

Comment: when I am compiling its giving error: "method setWorkingDirectory in interface Executor cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: what exactly I want iis to achieve is to run: 1) cd /tg (2) bin/telegram-cli (3) contact_list and to print command contact_list output with my java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as though it would be easier just to use ProcessBuilder instead.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bin/telegram-cli","-k","tg-server.pub","-W","-U","root");
pb.directory(new File("/var/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/Telegram/tg"));
Process p = pb.start();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()),true)) {
    String line = null;
    pw.println("contact_list");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("line = " + line);
    }
}
```

**Update**
It looks like the writes with PrintWriter need to be flushed. You can do this by calling `pw.flush()` or adding the second argument `true` to the PrintWriter constructor.  I don't know the commands for telegram-cli, but you need to add one that will produce an output you can use to identify when to quit. Here's an example using /bin/sh.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh");
Process p = pb.start();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()),true)) {
    String line = null;
    pw.println("ls");
    pw.println("pwd");
    pw.println("echo quit"); // this gives me output I can test for to break the loop
    pw.flush();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.contains("quit")) {
        System.out.println("line = " + line);
    }
}
int retcode = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("process ended with " + retcode);
```

Produces this output:

```
line = build
line = build.xml
line = dist
line = manifest.mf
line = nbproject
line = src
line = /home/shackle/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication20
process ended with 0
```

Comment: line = Telegram-cli uses libpython version 2.6.6
line = I: config dir=[/root/.telegram-cli]
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
line = > 
Its starting endless loop

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart. how can I use other commands when bin/telegram-cli... starts e.g. contact_list or msg user msgtext??

Comment: The above code not executing pw.println("contact_list");

Comment: Thanks for your favorable replies but unfortunately its not initiating the commands that is used by Telegram-API. Is there a way in Java to start a program in linux and then invoke its commands?

Comment: The example above is starting the linux program /bin/sh and invoking its commands ls and pwd. Is that example working for you?  Be sure your using the latest version of the example that flushes the output stream. ls should return a list of files in your current directory, and pwd prints the current directory.

Comment: Thanks again WillShackleford7. Its working with ls and pwd but not working with telegram-cli API as you stated in your first example. Can you please check https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api and advise how can I deploy it?

Comment: I think that is rather far from the original question title of "interacting with linux shell prompt in java".  I would suggest you ask a new question "How to get the contact list (or whatever else you want )from Telegram using Java?"  Be sure to add the telegram tag to attract the attention of  someone more familiar with this than me.

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart